# How to create your own SecureContext for TLS 1.2?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, tls1.2, pfx

I am using nodejs for TLS 1.2 requests to a server, which requires client authentication. This means, that during the inital handshake the client has sign a hash value over random values negotiated between client and server.

In nodejs you have to supply the (e.g. RSA) key or the .pfx/.p12 file along with the according passphrase with the request:

```
var https = require('https'), fs = require('fs')
var options = {
    host: url, path: func, method: 'POST',
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('mycert.pfx'),
    passphrase: 'mysecret',
    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'
}
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
...
```

In fact you are handing out your signature infrastructure instead of just signing a single item.

Customers don't want that, they insist in usage of Windows Certificate Store for signature, or, even better, use a hardware token (smartcard, HSM) or a remote Key Vault that administers and protocols signature creation.

For this I would need a "sign" callback when the basic TLS handshake is done.

I've seen, that nodejs is using a SecureContext object, which is created by TLS.createSecureContext(). Is it possible to replace this object by your own implementation? What is its functional interface? Has anybody already done that?

Any other ideas?

Comment: It's probably not easily possible. Have you thought about using a web server such as Apache or nginx in front of node.js to configure this properly?

Comment: Designed as lightweight node.js service the app should not rely on external infrastructure. But thank you, your answer shows, that other systems are more versitale in this respect.